# Unable to run Ansible with sudo user

Tags: linux, shell, ansible, ansible-2.x

We have a user `userA` on the server which has access to `sudo`. I can login into the server and run `sudo su - userA` to switch to new user. However if I use Ansible, it is throwing me below error:

> fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to node1 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "\r\nSorry, user abc is not allowed to execute '/bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS-pzwmlpcvzvwafleunmvpwioi; /usr/bin/python /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1533926060.36-184244176073120/setup.py' as userA on node1.\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1}

Ansible file:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_user: userA
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
      - name: Create file
        command: touch /home/userA/testing
```

We don't have access to sudoers file. Is there a way to fix this without changing sudoers file?

Answer (score 2):

I depends... If the sudoers configuration permits running `/usr/bin/su - userA*` (with a wildcard at the end allowing for the `-c` argument), then you can add become-configuration to your task in the following way:

```
- name: Create file
  command: touch /home/userA/testing
  vars:
    ansible_become: true
    ansible_become_method: su
    ansible_become_user: userA
    ansible_become_exe: 'sudo -p "Password: " su -'
```

If the password is required by sudoers, you must run `ansible-playbook` with `--ask-become-pass` (`-K`) option and connecting user's password (as for `sudo`).

<sup>First three parameters can be written directly as parameters to the task / play.</sup>

---

Otherwise you are probably destined for running `expect` module (likely on the controller machine) with all the drawbacks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @techraf. However, our servers does not allow us to run any su commands. We are able to achive this is java using tts. is there way to do this in ansible?

Comment: Read your own question please: "*I can login into the server and run `sudo su - userA`*".

Comment: That's right it is allowing me to run `sudo su - userA` but not `/bin/sh -c`. If I use the same syntax as you suggested it is throwing me this error `fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: "}`

Answer (score 0):

you can SetUID `chmod u+s file` on the files you want to run with UserA from userB. For Example, /usr/bin/passwd is a root file which has SetUID, so, any user can change its own passwd (using passwd command) while running the /usr/bin/passwd as root.

```
ls -l /usr/bin/passwd
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 27832 Jun 10  2014 /usr/bin/passwd

passwd
Changing password for user user.
Changing password for user.
(current) UNIX password:
```

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: you're right, it doesn't NOW. i.e.  after the question is edited, when I answered to the question, the question didn't have Ansible File and a disclaimer stating no sudoers file access. See revisions- (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51796405/revisions).

Comment: I see the question was "*is there a way to fix this without changing sudoers file?*" from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run a command as Another User, you can try something as below:

- become: yes
- become_user: userA
- ansible_become_pass: userA